# how to find the CSS/HTML rule that determine the color of specific pixel

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-devtools, bookmarklet

Using chrome, my website has some strange rectangle with light blue color. I have no idea where does this rectangle coming from as my DOM is very complex and not entirely in my control.

My question is: can I use chrome devtools to get the list  HTML/CSS rules that determine the color of a pixel of my choosing? if not, is there some app that I can use? Maybe  some JavaScript bookmarklet?

edit: I am aware of the element tab, but searching there did not help as the rule is complicated and I cant find it in the tree

Comment: You can not select it in dev tools by clicking on the blue border?

Comment: In an HTML/CSS context, elements don't normally appear out of thin air with no HTML backing them. You should in most all cases be able to use Chrome's devtools to inspect the element that is generating this rectangle of which you speak and investigate from there.

Comment: So when does it happen? Is it always on the page? Does it happen on hover, focus, click, licking the screen*, dancing, etc?

Comment: @epascarello it is always there and not affected by mouse movement,

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a focus highlight: https://www.washington.edu/accessibility/checklist/focus/ You should keep some form of highlight for accessibility purposes, however you can modify the color for aesthetics keeping in mind color contrast https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/